# APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY in azure function app config

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

does APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY in the config have to be uppercase in azure function app?

Answer (score 0):

It could be in lower case also.

[image]

I tried this and works fine for me. It should be an unique key though.

Comment: I see that it is populated in the config. My question is does ApplicationInsights care about the case or is it to have the variable defined in the lowercase?

Comment: It is populated in Upper case, so should maintain that. However I tried with lower case and tested. It seems that application insight still works in the same manner. Did you observe otherwise?